# Google Maps Services causes no element found error

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, build-error

I have problem with building my Android app with Google play services.
I created blank project and everything works correctly.
When I add Google Play Services - Maps with via Xamarin component store, it throws error while building

```
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\43F377EEC1C255C75E6502EF6329CABA\res\values-mk-rMK\base_strings.xml(2): error APT0000: Error parsing XML: no element found
```

[image: Building Error]

I think `base_strings.xml` is an automatically generated file, because it is empty

Could you help me with this?

Comment: can you manually put a base_string.xml file in that path  with valid XML tags in it, just to see if it can still run? Also look at your project to see if you can find that file anywhere, particularly: src\main\res\values\

Comment: also make sure your app's Target Framework and Target Android version to Android 5.0

Comment: Also ensure your manifest has proper permissions, and your DEVELOPER keys are properly referenced. You need to enable Maps from your Google Play Developer Console, to ensure proper functionality.

Comment: I tried manually put valid xml to base_strings.xml, but it is overwritten on rebuild.
[link](https://s16.postimg.org/elkzp2hvp/Untitled4.png)
Target framework changed to 5.0 but results are same.
I know that I need Google maps API Key to proper funcionality, but it is needed after successfull build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by uninstalling Visual Studio with VisualStudioUninstaller https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases

Answer (score 0):

I also tried create crossplatform solution, and when I add google playservices base it will throw this error: Error parsing XML: no element found

Comment: Hi, probably problem is in Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps, because if I update to 32.940.0-beta3 it is possible to rebuild, but after this I am not able to reference Xamarin.Forms.Maps because of compatibility issue.